# javascript slider showing different images to each value

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

im working on a slider in html, that will show different images depending on the slider value.

so if the slider is set to value 1, image1.jpg is shown, value 2 will show image2.jpg and so on.

I have found the slider part on w3schools and has managed to output new images to it.   [link to w3schools slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_rangeslider_round)

But i dont know how to refresh the images, for now the code just prints a new one by the olds images side. i++

does anyone know how to refresh image, instead of printing a one new every time.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;

  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", "image" + this.value + ".jpg");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="2" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to show images based on the value? Please share your effort with us!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have noe clue how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Well, then [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and try to find out how to do it. If you encounter a **specific** problem, ask a question about that including a [mcve] of what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: img = "/path_to_your_image_folder/image" + slider.value + ".jpg";

Comment: so i have figured how to change picture to value, but does anyone know how to refresh picture instead of printing a new one by its side? question code is updated.  thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `img` *element* with the default image or `src` *value*:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;

  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/" + this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/1" alt="" id="img">
</div>
```